# Block initialized ViewController gets released to early

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, objective-c-blocks

I'm initalizing a SubViewController in a block. I'm adding the view of the view controller as subview to my MainViewcontroller. My SubViewController has some button logic in it.
What happens now that when I press the button in the subview the app crashes because the SubViewController was already released.

I'm afraid this is a major design problem - but at the moment I don't have any clue how to  avoid this.

This how the initialization looks in my block statement

```
__strong AAFBPostView *newPost = [[AAFBPostView alloc]init];
newPost.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 88);
[self.view addSubview:newPost.view];
[newPost setData:result]; //passing some data to the view
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the APIs for container view controllers. This is all covered in the docs for `UIViewController`.

The problem with your code is there is no strong reference to the `AAFBPostView` view controller once the `newPost` variable goes out of scope. BTW - your view controller's class name should be `AAFBPostViewController`. The current name implies it is a view, not a view controller.

By using the container API, the parent view controller keeps a reference to the child view controller so the problem is fixed.

Details can be found in the [Creating Custom Content View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW1) section of the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".

Comment: Yeah you're right the name is a bit messy. I'll look into container view controllers

Comment: Adding the line: `[self addChildViewController:newPost];` solves my problem! Great thank you! I can't believe that I never saw this problem after nearly 2 years of iOS developing :/

Comment: You to do a bit more than call that one method. Be sure you read the guide I linked to for all of the details.